# How to get instances of simple_html_dom's function to use in a class

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have class `ClassA` and want to use simple_html_dom's function in this class. How can I do that?
This's link of simple_html_dom class http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/366382/simple-html-dom-rar.html

Comment: `class A { public $dom; function __construct(){$this->dom = new DOMDocument; } }`

Comment: Thanks man, but I need to do things I posted in my comment below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    Class A
    {
        private $simpleHTML;

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->simpleHTML = new simple_html_dom(); 
            //now you can call all simple html functions using $this->simpleHTML->..
        }

        //define file_get_html as a class method. You can call this as 
        // $x = new A();
        //$x->file_get_html..(externally) or $this->file_get_html(.. (internally)
        function file_get_html($url, 
                        $use_include_path = false, 
                        $context=null, $offset = -1, 
                        $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, 
                        $forceTagsClosed=true, 
                        $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, 
                        $stripRN=true, 
                        $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
        {
            // We DO force the tags to be terminated.
            $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $defaultBRText);
            // For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
            $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
            // Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to control the timeout.
            //$contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
            if (empty($contents))
            {
                return false;
            }
            // The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
            $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
            return $dom;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: simple html dom have `function file_get_html()` ouside the class simple_html_dom. I have to call it! `simple html dom` is a custom library for php

Comment: I do not know if I understand you correctly, but if the library is defined as a class, you can have an object of that class instantiated inside the constructor of class A and then call it as a member of the class right?

Comment: I have posted simple_html_dom file in my updated question. Please check it out! Thanks for your help!:D

Comment: @quanganh_developer: updated my answer, check if that helps your situation. Btw, McAfee warns that download in the link you gave contains viruses! :o

Comment: Oh man! I don't think it have viruses,:(! I used it for a long time.
How about `function file_get_html()` in simple_html_dom library. It stand outside the simple_html_dom class. How can I call it?

Comment: @quanganh_developer: No, I downloaded from sourceforge. In order to use file_get_html() inside the class simply define it inside your class and you are good to go..I have updated my answer. I have copy-pasted the function from sourceforge, the version you have might be a bit different, but the basic premise of implementing is the same..